# @Pattern annotation causing NullPointerException in OpenAPI 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi

I have a service with Spring Boot 3, OpenAPI 3 and Spring Webflux.

Everything was working untill now, but suddenly when I added a `@Pattern` annotation I started getting a NullPointerException when I try to access my OpenAPI endpoint.

Here's my endpoint:

```
@Operation(summary = "Busca no banco de dados de filial através de um identificador numérico.", description = "Recebe um identificador numérico de filial e busca no banco de dados.")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_200, description = "Vendedor encontrada e dados retornados com sucesso.", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = VendedorResponseModel.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_400, description = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION_STATUS_CODE_400, content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorAttributes.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_404, description = "Vendedor não encontrada.", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorAttributes.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_422, description = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION_STATUS_CODE_422, content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorAttributes.class))),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_STATUS_CODE_500, description = ConstantsPresentation.RESPONSE_DESCRIPTION_STATUS_CODE_500, content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorAttributes.class))) })
Mono<VendedorResponseModel> findByID(
        @NotNull(message = "Não pode passar um id nulo para esta busca.") @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d+-(OUT|CLT|PJ)$", message = "A matrícula deve seguir um padrão numérico, seguido de um hífen e terminando com as letras OUT, CLT ou PJ. Exemplo: 98767367-OUT.") @Parameter(description = "O identificador numérico de uma filial.", example = "98767367-OUT", name = "matricula", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class, pattern = "^\\d+-(OUT|CLT|PJ)$"))) String matricula);
```

The console log:

```
2023-05-15T19:58:39.939-03:00[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m3616[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ctor-http-nio-6][0;39m [36ma.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler[0;39m [2m:[0;39m [48b429d2-9]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/v3/api-docs"

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Schema.setPattern(String)" because "schema" is null
    at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.applyValidationsToSchema(AbstractRequestService.java:709) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/v3/api-docs" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.applyValidationsToSchema(AbstractRequestService.java:709) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.applyBeanValidatorAnnotations(AbstractRequestService.java:587) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.core.service.AbstractRequestService.build(AbstractRequestService.java:338) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:474) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.calculatePath(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:654) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$calculatePath$5(OpenApiResource.java:191) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.calculatePath(OpenApiResource.java:173) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.lambda$getPaths$0(OpenApiResource.java:157) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.getPaths(OpenApiResource.java:149) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:334) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:119) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiWebfluxResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebfluxResource.java:114) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.lambda$invoke$0(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:145) ~[spring-webflux-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:293) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:474) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:466) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.request(MonoZip.java:216) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer$HttpServerHandle.onStateChange(HttpServer.java:1006) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onStateChange(ReactorNetty.java:710) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.transport.ServerTransport$ChildObserver.onStateChange(ServerTransport.java:481) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:633) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:228) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I tried to set the pattern attibute of the Schema value, but still not working. When I remove the `@Pattern` annotation the OpenAPI starts, but the service does not trigger the validation.

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my parent POM:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.6</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Am I using the annotation in the incorrect place? All other validation annotations seem to work.